# openCV - imshow at 120 fps

Tags: opencv, avi, imshow

I'm working with openCV GPU processing a video file at 120 fps. My question is: Can I display the processed images at the same frame rate? When I'm displaying images using imshow the fps decreases to 20~30. Can I display these images faster (up to 120 fps)?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if you will be able "display" the frames @ 120 fps; the only thing I can suggest you to try is putting `cv::waitKey(1/120)` after your highgui window and see what happens.

Comment: Hello scap3y it increases the frame rate to 50 fps do you have another suggestion? Why do you think it's not possible to display frames at 120 fps?

Comment: You can try to setup a window with a 3D graphic context (OpenGL) and then send these images to the GPU do be displayed.

Comment: Karlphilip, thanks for your comment. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @scap3y Its not waitKey(1/120), its waitKey(1000/120) ~= 1frame per 8seconds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to make sure that your display (LCD, Monitor, screen, etc) can really redraw at 120 fps first.  Even if the display runs faster, some computer systems limit the update rate.

Comment: My display only can refresh to 60 fps; Thanks for reply!!